# how to add +91 prefix in phone number field in magento 2 checkout form

Tags: magento2

Hi there I want to have prefix +91 in Magento 2 checkout form phone number field how can i achieve this kindly share the files to edit I am new to magento2 
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

> You can use the below extension to achieve your requirement

1. https://magecomp.com/magento-2-international-telephone-input.html
2. https://github.com/MaxMage/international-telephone-input